# jquery dialog in updatepanel with repeater

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

i got a updatepanel with a repeater in it. it display different events that i get from a calendar.

now what it want for it to do is i click on a event and it should display in a jquery dialog.

now this works great if i am not using a updatepanel but with it just wont work.

i been looking for it yesterday for some time and i seen some articles but i stil wont get the solution i am looking for..

```
    $(document).ready(function() {                 
                $("#btnCheck").click(function(evt) {
                    evt.preventDefault();                               

                    $(".dialog").dialog({ height: 700, width: 600, 
closeOnEscape: true, title: 'prev' }).dialog("open");
                });           
            });
```

```
        <div class="calendar_event_div">
            <asp:Repeater ID="repContent" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repContent_OnItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="repContent_OnItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>                        
                    <asp:Literal ID="lbnEvent" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Literal ID="litEventBody" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Where is the element with the class of 'dialog'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use livequery.

```
$("#btnCheck").live("click", function(evt){

    // your code

});
```

This method works and behaves very similarly to jQuery's bind method but with one important distinction: When you bind a "live" event it will bind to all current and future elements loaded by update panel controls.

Comment: i will bring back solution soon

Answer (score 2):

Try to register your javascript with with the `ScriptManager.RegisterScriptBlock(...)`, that will cause the js to be firered inside a updatepanel.

Also you could play around with the live command. Live will keep an eye out for any new element with the selector and assign the event to that.

```
$("#btnCheck").live("click", function(){
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Johan, i will look into the scriptmanager soon. i did not know that

Comment: +1 for RegisterScriptBlock & you actually post answer 2 minutes earlier.